# How to generate bubble plot values for two groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to subset my data in ggplot based on two Groups: `Grp1` and `Grp2`. I want to subset and represent them distinctly. How do I do it?

`dput(df)`

```
structure(list(ID = c("pathway1", "pathway2", "pathway3", "pathway4","pathway5", "pathway1", "pathway2", "pathway3", "pathway4", "pathway5"),
               Hit = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 6L, 16L),
               Zscore = c(-1.3,-2, 2, 3, 1, -1.3, -2, 2, 3, 1),
               Group = c("Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I have tried following code:

```
f <- ggplot(data = df, aes(Zscore, ID, color = Group)) 
f1 <- f + geom_point(aes(size = Hit)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = 'Group',
    values = c("Grp1" = 'red', "Grp2" = 'blue')
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, size = 0.2, colour = "blue", linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray95", colour = "gray95"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray90"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray90"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-3, 3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Z-score', breaks = pretty(df$Zscore)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(df$ID)) + theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))

f1
```

It resulted in:
[image: output]

I want to get for each pathway what is the the NES score Group. Here it's shown only for one group

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `position_dodge` for your points:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(Zscore, ID, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(size = Hit), 
    position = position_dodge(.6)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Group",
    values = c("Grp1" = "red", "Grp2" = "blue")
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = 0, size = 0.2,
    colour = "blue", linetype = "dotted"
  ) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray95", colour = "gray95"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = "solid", colour = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = "solid", colour = "gray90"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-3, 3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Z-score", breaks = pretty(df$Zscore)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$ID))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image]